# How to pass selected bootstrap dropdown value to the controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I inherited this code base in which I need to pass extra property to the controller. This field happens to be a select dropdown for users to select yes or no. I need to pass that value to the controller.

The new property I am adding is `RecurringPayment`, I have already added the property to the model, but I am unable to pass the selected Yes or No to the controller. I am getting null in the controller

I have tried the code below with the bootstrap dropdown.

```
<!-- This is the select drop down -->
<div class="payment-body pl-3 pr-3">
    <div class="pay-option-btns py-4">
        <select asp-for="" id="RecurringPayment" 
                name="RecurringPayment" asp-items="@Model.RecurringPayment">
            <option value="">Recurring payment?</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
        </select>

        <!-- This is the inherited code -->
        <button class="px-3 rounded border-0 pay-with-transfer mt-2 mt-lg-0" type="button" style="font-size: 12px" onclick="callGamma()">
            <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="mr-2">
                <path d="M11.5  10V17H7V10H4Z" fill="white" />
            </svg>
            <span class="text-capitalize text-white">Pay with Gamma</span>
        </button>
        <a href="@Url.Action("MakePayment", "Payment", new {email = Model.Email, amount = Model.Total, reference = Model.ProposalNumber, RecurringPayment = Model.RecurringPayment } )" class="px-3 rounded border-0 d-flex align-items-center pay-with-transfer mt-2 mt-lg-0" style="font-size: 12px">
            <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="mr-2">
                <path d="6.4127Z" fill="white" />
            </svg>
            <span class="text-capitalize text-white" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Please note that your subsequent premium will be charged automatically base on your policy">pay with paystack</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have also tried using `DropDownListFor`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.RecurringPayment,
                      new List<SelectListItem> {
                            new SelectListItem { Value="", Text = "Do you want recurring changes" },
                            new SelectListItem { Value="Yes", Text = "Yes" },
                            new SelectListItem { Value="No", Text = "No" }
                      },
                      new { @class = "myselect" })
```

But I got an error:

> CS0136: A local variable named 'Model' cannot be declared in this
> scope because it would give a different meaning to 'Model', which is
> already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

Controller method:

```
public ActionResult MakePayment(string email, double amount, string reference, string RecurringPayment)
{
    PaystackRequest request = new PaystackRequest()
                                  { 
                                      amount = amount, 
                                      email = email, 
                                      reference = reference, 
                                      RecurringPayment = RecurringPayment 
                                  };

    var result = apicall.Payment(request);

    return Redirect(result);
}
```

Comment: *"I am unable to pass the selected Yes or No to the controller"*.. Please include your controller code

Comment: I have added controller code

Comment: looks ok-- will you include the full <form> tag code

Comment: @techstack: Start from changing `@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.RecurringPayment` to `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.RecurringPayment`.

Comment: @Jackdaw I have made the change, and the error is gone. But I am still getting null value for RecurringPayment in the controller. How can the selected value be passed to the controller? thanks

Comment: @techstack: Does the `RecurringPayment` defined as `public string RecurringPayment {get; set;}`?

Comment: @Jackdaw Yes, that is done in the PayViewModel

Answer (score 0):

You can make the following changes to get your selected value from the drop down list in your `Controller` method:

First assign an `id` attribute to your drop down list:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.RecurringPayment,
                      new List<SelectListItem> {
                            new SelectListItem { Value="", Text = "Do you want recurring changes" },
                            new SelectListItem { Value="Yes", Text = "Yes" },
                            new SelectListItem { Value="No", Text = "No" }
                      },
                      new { @class = "myselect", @id = "ddlPayment" })
```

Now, you can read the value from the current Request using [Request.Form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525985(v=vs.90)):

```
public ActionResult MakePayment(string email, double amount, string reference)
{
    string selectedDDLValue= Convert.ToString(Request.Form["ddlPayment"]);
    PaystackRequest request = new PaystackRequest()
                                  { 
                                      amount = amount, 
                                      email = email, 
                                      reference = reference, 
                                      RecurringPayment = RecurringPayment 
                                  };

    var result = apicall.Payment(request);

    return Redirect(result);
}
```

Alternatively, you need to send the `Model` to your `Controller` instead of sending it a as a `string`:

```
public ActionResult MakePayment(string email, double amount, string reference, RecurringPayment recurringpayment)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RecurringPayment,
                      new List<SelectListItem> {
                            new SelectListItem { Value="", Text = "Do you want recurring changes" },
                            new SelectListItem { Value="Yes", Text = "Yes" },
                            new SelectListItem { Value="No", Text = "No" }
                      },
                      new { @class = "myselect" })
```

`model => model.RecurringPayment` instead of `Model => Model.RecurringPayment`.